# Spring boot 1.4 Integration tests pass but Application start fails

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test

We just upgraded to Spring Boot 1.4 and are using the Spring Boot testing improvements. We have integration tests of the form:

```
RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
    ApplicationConfiguration.class }, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ServiceIntegrationTest {
private static final String AEndpoint = Constants.A_REST_CONTROLLER_ENDPOINT;
private static final String TEndpoint = Constants.T_REST_CONTROLLER_ENDPOINT;

@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

public void postJsonNode(String postUrl, JsonNode requestBody) {
    HttpEntity<JsonNode> request = new HttpEntity<JsonNode>(requestBody, this.headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> post = this.testRestTemplate.postForEntity(postUrl, request, String.class);
    assertThat(post.getStatusCode(), equalTo(HttpStatus.CREATED));
}
```

These kinds of tests pass but the Application fails to start due to ObjectMapper getting deprecated and replaced by a pre-wired _halMapper (I referred to as bean wiring issue).

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Constructor in  org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointMBeanExportAutoConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
- objectMapper: defined by method 'objectMapper' in com.service.ApplicationConfiguration
- _halObjectMapper: defined in null
```

Application class:

```
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfiguration.class, args);
}
}
```

ApplicationConfiguration class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.service")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    return objectMapper;
}

}
```

Is there a way to test the Application start through integration tests?

Comment: What do you main application class and its main method look like?

Comment: *"some bean wiring issue"*?

Comment: Are you using the same profile for integration tests as you use to run the application?

Comment: @LakatosGyula: Yes I am using the same profile for tests and main application.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Just updated my post with the code

Comment: @kryger I explicitly mention what "bean wiring issue" it failed on. Deprecation of ObjectMapper in 1.4 and getting a halMapper wired for free. The ObjectMapper was part of the config class